# Is it bad practice to use an empty base class to force inheritance for an abstract factory?

Tags: c++, factory, abstract-factory

I have a class called A, and say a few inherited classes based off A.
I'm not including them here to save some space but also assume we have derived classes for A which would require the need for a factory. Same for class B.

```
struct A
{
    ...
}; 

struct B
{
    ...
};

// start of factory code
//
struct empty_base_factory
{
};

struct factoryA : public empty_base_factory
{
    shared_ptr<A> make_object() { return ... }
};

struct factoryB : public empty_base_factory
{
    shared_ptr<B> make_object() { return ... }
};

class abstract_factory
{
    std::map< uint8_t, std::shared_ptr<empty_base_factory> > iv_factories;

    public:
        abstract_factory()
        {
            iv_factories[0] = make_shared<factoryA>();
            iv_factories[1] = make_shared<factoryB>();
           // .. I might several more similar to this
        }

        std::shared_ptr<empty_base_factory> make_factory(const uint8_t i_key)
        {
             return iv_factories[i_key];
        }
};
```

It feels like I'm forcing an unnatural inheritance for with the empty_base_factory in order to get this implementation I found in a book to work nicely.  It would make sense for make_object to be an interface method to make empty_base_factory an interface but the return type of make_object is different and I'm not sure how to handle that.

Is this a poor way of trying to implement an abstract factory  by forcing the use of an empty base class? Thoughts?

Comment: That seems a scenario not suitable for inheritance: at the end, client code will have to call make_object, but its return type will be different for every concrete factory class, so it seems some compile time polymorphism (template?) is the way to go. But maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a poor way of trying to implement an abstract factory by
>   forcing the use of an empty base class? Thoughts?

You don't need "`empty_base_factory`" if it's just empty.

In the [Abstract Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) design pattern:

> The abstract factory pattern provides a way to encapsulate a group of
>   individual factories that have a common theme without specifying their
>   concrete classes

In your case: `abstract_factory` depends on `factoryA` and `factoryB` (which are your concrete factories) to create a concrete object. User doesn't know anything about these concrete factories' existence.

Going back to your question: It is not really related about the Abstract Factory design pattern.

There's no stopping you to define an abstract base class, `BaseFactory`, which defines what are the basic functionalities of a factory (eg. `make_object()`). The virtual functions in `BaseFactory` are what your concrete factories should implement.

Comment: So you mean having the AbstractFactory define a `shared_ptr<AbstractFactory> make_object(..) = 0`, then the make_object overrides for struct A would be somewhere along the line of `shared_ptr<AbstractFactory> make_object (..) { return make_shared<factoryA>(...)` instead of what I have defined above right?

Comment: @user1945925, you should return the concrete object and not the factory.

Comment: Oh I misread that, that makes sense.  The part I'm still confused about is what the return type of the virtual method for `make_object` would be in the BaseFactory since Struct A and Struct B don't share a common base class.

Comment: @user1945925, create a `struct BaseObject` which will be the return for the abstract factory. see the link provided, there are examples.